# How to install *.deb package using Dpkg to specific directory.

Tags: command-line, python, dpkg

I have to install two packages (libidb and python-idb and both are depended to each other ) from third party.So,we can not get access of source code.
I have tried with these following method to install and i got error also:

```
> > sumitkumars@administrator-Lenovo-U410:~$ sudo dpkg -i libidb-0.12.0-0b81d72-0.amd64.deb --instdir=/home/sumitkumars/mydir
> [sudo] password for sumitkumars:  (Reading database ... 186372 files
> and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
> libidb-0.12.0-0b81d72-0.amd64.deb ... Unpacking libidb (0.12.0) over
> (0.12.0) ... dpkg: error processing archive
> --instdir=/home/sumitkumars/mydir (--install):  cannot access archive: No such file or directory Setting up libidb (0.12.0) ... Errors were
> encountered while processing:  --instdir=/home/sumitkumars/mydir
```

then i tried with this:

```
sumitkumars@administrator-Lenovo-U410:~$ sudo dpkg-deb -x libidb-0.12.0-0b81d72-0.amd64.deb /home/sumitkumars/mydir/
```

It is not giving error but it was not working with its another depency(python-idb)

I have added python also because it is unable to bind with "libidb".

Answer (score 12):

```bsh
dpkg-deb -x $DEBFILE $TARGET_DIRECTORY

# Example 
dpkg-deb -x somedeb.deb /home/yung/test
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077151/set-install-path-using-dpkg)

Comment: This works to some extent, but creates a dir named "usr" inside `/home/yung/test` which then contains `lib` and `share`. If your `lib` and your `share` directories are inside `$TARGET_DIRECTORY`, this won't work.

Comment: Decompressing is not the same as installing, e.g. `postinst`, `prerm` etc scripts are not run. Using `--instdir=/path/to/root` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

A .deb is just an archive, like a zip file

You can manually extract it ; https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-extract-a-deb-file-without-opening-it-on-debian-or-ubuntu-linux/

```
sudo apt install binutils

ar x your.deb
```

You then extract the .tar or whatever is in the .deb

```
tar xvf control.tar.gz
tar data.tar.gz
```

You can then manually copy the files to wherever you wish, I would use /usr/local so they are on your path, up to you.

You may need to read / run the config files and install scripts as well, cant say from what you have posted.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use `dpkg-deb` for unpacking packing `.deb` files since it doesn't need to have something new to be installed?

Comment: I am neutral on that ;)

Comment: @Panther Thanks ,do i have to bind two library if both(libidb and python-idb) are complement to each other.

Comment: @SumitKumarSuman I do not know I am not familiar with your package.

Answer (score 6):

In all other answers recommending decompressing archive -- that is not the same as installing! One of the notable differences is that `postinst` script is not run when using `-x`.
The only satisfactory answer to the OPs question is this option, straight from man pages:

```
       --instdir=dir
              Change default installation directory which refers to the
              directory where packages are to be installed. instdir is also the 
              directory passed to chroot(2) before running package's installation 
              scripts, which means that the scripts see instdir as a root
              directory.  (Defaults to «/»)
```

Comment: doesnt work for me. give error: `dpkg (subprocess): admindir must be inside instdir for dpkg to work properly`

Comment: Same error message as above. I'm assuming `--instdir` is need to update chroots or recover systems. Did you check this works before posting it?

Comment: from the manpage, the admindir needs to be indeed inside instdir; this can be done via the --root option, which sets instdir to 'dir' and then admindir to 'dir/var/lib/dpkg'. I'm assuming two separate ways of doing this exist in case you wanted to do 'dir' vs ''dir/some/other/path/dpkg' instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to extract the package contents of these two packages, only because they are dependent on each other.

Just give both packages at once when installing

```
dpkg -i libidb-0.12.0-0b81d72-0.amd64.deb python-idb-<version>.amd64.deb
```

Comment: This is not what's asked.

Comment: @dimir Yes, this is not an answer to the question. But it is a solution to the problem of installing dependent packages.