# How to install .deb packages in a custom folder different from root (/) using dpkg?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I have to install some `.deb` packages in a subdirectory, namely `/opt/corbos-linux/2.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/`. This folder should be used as the new root. I tried to install these packages using

```
dpkg --root=/opt/corbos-linux/2.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/ -i *.deb
```

but this error comes up:

```
dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: No such file or directory
```

While if I give

```
dpkg --instdir=/opt/corbos-linux/2.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/ -i *.deb
```

this error appears for most of the packages:

```
dpkg (subprocess): admindir must be inside instdir for dpkg to work properly
```

Some extra information: all the commands are executed with root privilege and in the folder containing the `.deb` packages (note that if I simply run `dpkg -i *.deb` in, say, `/home/folder_containing_debs`, packages are installed correctly, but not in the location that I want). The operating system is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (x86-64 architecture)

Answer (score 3):

You probably looking for this:

```html
dpkg-deb -x $YourDebFile $TARGET_DIRECTORY

# Example 
dpkg-deb -x <file_name>.deb /opt/corbos-linux/2.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/
```

[Found Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1142323/1103062)

---

Update:
---
You can install all `.deb` packages with simple command-line loop.

For Example, this is your current *"files and folders"* and you want to install all these `.deb` files to `/home/username/testing/` directory:

```html
some_deb_file.deb
another_file.deb
other/
testing/
```

For this you can run these commands:

```html
ls -1 | grep [.]deb >> all_debs.txt
cat all_debs.txt | while read fn; do dpkg-deb -x $fn /home/username/testing; done
rm all_debs.txt
```

### Code Explanation:

---

1. We create `all_debs.txt` file with all `.deb` file names inside it. *In our case file will look like this:* **NOTE: If your one package depends on another one, then you can edit this file and order the file names as you want.**

```html
some_deb_file.deb
another_file.deb
```

2. We loop inside file, taking line *("file name")*, and installing it using `dpkg-deb -x <file_name> <path>` structure.
3. Deleting file that we created at the beginning.

---

One line code for nerds ***:)*** :

```html
ls -1 | grep [.]deb >> all_debs.txt && cat all_debs.txt | while read fn; do dpkg-deb -x $fn /home/username/testing; done && rm all_debs.txt
```

Hope it helps! Have a great day! :D

Comment: This throws `dpkg-deb: error: --extract takes at most two arguments (.deb and directory)` error

Comment: For testing I did ```dpkg-deb -x figlet_2.2.5-3_arm64.deb /home/myuser/test/```, and it worked fine. _(You probably wrote additional things after command. Error says we should use only **two arguments**, and so we did. I think command should work great.)_

Comment: Ok, the thing is that I'm trying to install all `.deb` packages at one time. If I install one at time it works fine. I could overcome this problem with a simple loop but.. do I get problems if one package depends on another one that has not been installed yet?

Comment: @Luigi2405 Currently it isn't possible without loop. _(At least I don't know.)_ But, I updated my answer and provided script, and its explanation for that! Hope it helps! :)

Comment: thanks for your help. I succeded to install the library in the desired location but when I compile a bunch of errors pop out. I report one for each type of them: `/opt/corbos-linux/2.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-poky-linux/usr/include/stdio.h:351:1: error: '__BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD' does not name a type; did you mean '__BEGIN_DECLS'?`, `/opt/corbos-linux/2.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-poky-linux/usr/include/stdio.h:295:1: error: '__END_NAMESPACE_STD' does not name a type` and  `/opt/corbos-linux/2.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-poky-linux/usr/include/stdio.h:242:20: error: 'FILE' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Note that those libraries that now throw errors have been working correctly up to now. @ahmedg I know this is out of the scope of this question but if you know what could be a possible reason I would be very thankful. Thanks again in any case

Comment: One extra info. The library has indeed been found, but this weird message appears:
`-- Checking for module 'glib-2.0'
--   /opt/corbos-linux/2.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/pkg-config: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done`

Comment: Most of the time, these errors appear when compiling C++ code. When C++ gets an error, it doesn't stop the code, instead throws more _"unrelated"_ error messages. I think the package you compiling has and error itself. Again, I hope it helps, but I don't know much about compiling errors. :)

Answer (score 1):

one liner to install multiple deps in one folder:

```
ls -1 *.deb | xargs -i sudo dpkg-deb -x {} /path/to/folder
```

ls will list deb packages, xargs loops over the list and executes the dpkg-deb command replacing {} with the filename from the list